# How can we find big O notation for trailing zeros in factorial?

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, big-o, factorial

I know how to calculate big O notation for factorial but I am having difficulty combining both notations.
this is the code for calculating trailing zeros.

```
using namespace std;

  // Function to return trailing 
  // 0s in factorial of n
 int findTrailingZeros(int n)
 {
   // Initialize result
    int count = 0;

    // Keep dividing n by powers of 
    // 5 and update count
    for (int i = 5; n / i >= 1; i *= 5)
        count += n / i;

    return count;
}

// Driver Code
int main()
{
   int n = 100;
   cout << "Count of trailing 0s in " << 100
        << "! is " << findTrailingZeros(n);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: The time complexity for this is `O(log n)`.

Comment: Be aware that dividing by a constant is much faster than by some variable (compilers can strength-reduce it). That also allows you to cut out a variable. As an aside, why do you use `int` instead of `unsigned`? So, best rewrite as: `unsigned factorial_trailing_zeroes(unsigned n) { unsigned r = 0; while ((n /= 5)) ++r; return r; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complexity is `O(log(n))`. Its easy to see if you plot the number of iterations for each `n`:

```
n        iterations
------   -----------
< 5      0
< 25     1
< 125    2
< 625    3
< 3125   4
```

Comment: what will be the complexity of just calculating trailing zeros?

Comment: what do you mean? does this not already answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

To be precise it should be 
   O(1 - log5(n)) = O(log5(n)) where n is the number whose factorial is to be determined.

Comment: O(log_5 n) is the same thing as O(log n).

Comment: log n commonly is log2(n)

Comment: The base of the logarithm doesn't matter, because the logarithmic functions only differ by constant factors, which are irrelevant in big O notation.

Answer (score -1):

5,5^2,5^3....5^k.
at last
5^k<=n(given in for loop)
so k<=log5(n)
so time complexity is thetha(logn)